# How to customise alert emails?

Tags: 2013, alert

I am using the Alert out of the box functionality for a document library whereby I am sending a daily summary email to all employees with new docs.

Is it possible to modify the information/fields that are displayed within the email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to dig deep and hope 2013 still does it the same as many moons ago.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0/

[only a link, no sense in pasting anything more]

Comment: You need administrator access to the server for this.Is there any other way?

Comment: No.. Rebuilt the alert mechanism with Workflows and you have all the control you want

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the fields that are displayed, you can modify the view to display a specific set on columns. Also, if you have a filtered view, you can set the alert to only trigger when items appear in that filtered view, and the alert email will display only the columns in that filtered view.

Aside from changing the columns, your best option would be to create a custom workflow to send out an email. You have a lot more control over the email contents. This will also support HTML in the email body for "pretty" emails.